# Mathematica style (drawing cubes)

Tags: graphics, code-review, coding-style

I wanted to draw (lattice-aligned) unit cubes inside a sphere with a given radius centered on the origin, so I wrote this program:

```
Cube[x_, y_, z_] := Cuboid[{x - 1, y - 1, z - 1}, {x, y, z}];
Coords[r_] := {#1, #2, Floor[Sqrt[r^2 - #1^2 - #2^2]]} & @@ # & /@ 
   With[{t = Sqrt[r^2 - 1]}, 
    Select[Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, 1, t}, {y, 1, x}], 1], 
     Norm[#] <= t &]];
Cubes[r_] := 
  Cube @@ # & /@ 
   Union[Flatten[Permute[#, SymmetricGroup[3]] & /@ Coords[r], 1]];
Draw[r_] := 
  Graphics3D[
   Union[Cubes[r], {{Green, Opacity[0.1], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]}}], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, r}, {0, r}, {0, r}}, 
   ViewPoint -> {r, 3 r/4, 3 r/5}];
Draw /@ Sqrt /@ {50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 2500, 6054}
```

(Note that it shows only the cubes on the outside -- drawing the inner ones takes too long and usually Mathematica runs out of memory.) It gets the job done, but it's pretty ugly. I'm not a regular Mathematica user, and tips for improving my code?

That is, how can I write idiomatically-better Mathematica code?

---

Improved code:

```
Coords[r_] := {#1, #2, Floor[Sqrt[r^2 - #1^2 - #2^2]]} & @@@ 
   With[{t = Sqrt[r^2 - 1]}, 
    Select[Join @@ Table[{x, y}, {x, t}, {y, 1, x}], Norm[#] <= t &]];
Cubes[r_] := (Cuboid /@ (Union @@ (Permute[#, SymmetricGroup[3]] & /@ 
         Coords[r]) - 1));
Draw[r_] := 
  Graphics3D[
   Union[Cubes[r], {{Green, Opacity[0.1], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]}}], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, r}, {0, r}, {0, r}}, 
   ViewPoint -> {r, 3 r/4, 3 r/5}];
Draw /@ Sqrt /@ {50, 100, 250}
```

Comment: Without examining the algorithm this looks like pretty good code to me.  In what way do you find it "ugly?"  I immediately see a few ways to make it shorter, e.g. `{x - 1, y - 1, z - 1}` can be written `{x, y, z} - 1`; are you interested in such things or does that just make it harder to read?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I'll take whatever tips I can get -- coding style, optimizations, etc. I'm new to Mathematica (but not to programming) and so to me it looks strange to see functional code on top of other styles, and I had to break the code into more helper functions than I wanted just to make it readable. It still seems very hard to read (vs. write).

Comment: You can drop `Cube` since it serves no purpose. E.g. `Graphics3D[Cuboid[{2, 3, 4}], Axes -> True]` will produce a unit cube aligned with the grid.

Comment: @DavidCarraher: I did not know that, thanks!

Comment: @David I feel foolish for overlooking that!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Easy to overlook. One rarely uses the `Cuboid` with a single point.

Comment: Since this is a question about coding style: do not use identifiers that start with a capital for interactive work. This way you'll avoid conflicts with builtin, future builtins, or packages.  I'm pretty sure there are packages out there which use `Draw` or `Cube` for something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Focusing only on syntax I think your code looks pretty good, but there are a few things I note that I think could be improved.

- The method `f @@ # & /@ expr` can be replaced with `f @@@ expr`, which is shorthand for `Apply[f, expr, {1}]`.  See [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html).
- You can use the listability of `Plus` to write `{x, y, z} - 1` instead of `{x - 1, y - 1, z - 1}`
- `Union[Flatten[expr, 1]]` can be written `Union @@ expr`

Your first three functions with these changes (among others), and David's observation regarding `Cuboid`:

```
Cube[x_, y_, z_] := Cuboid[{x, y, z} - 1];

Coords[r_] := {#1, #2, Floor[Sqrt[r^2 - #1^2 - #2^2]]} & @@@ 
   With[{t = Sqrt[r^2 - 1]},
     Select[Join @@ Table[{x, y}, {x, t}, {y, 1, x}], Norm[#] <= t &]];

Cubes[r_] := Cube @@@ Union @@ (Permute[#, SymmetricGroup[3]] & /@ Coords[r]);
```

Regarding style I think it is fairly personal whether or not something is easy to read, but here is an example of a different style which you may prefer:

```
Coords[r_] :=
  With[{t = Sqrt[r^2 - 1]},
    Cases[
      Join @@ Table[{x, y}, {x, t}, {y, 1, x}],
      {x_, y_} /; Norm[{x, y}] <= t :>
         {x, y, ⌊ Sqrt[r^2 - x^2 -y^2] ⌋ }
    ]
  ]
```

Fortunately *Mathematica* supports many different styles.

Comment: There's such a thing as `@@@`? Amazing! I thought `@@ # & /@` was a ridiculous hack, but I couldn't get it to work otherwise.

Comment: @Charles I added an example of a different style, both in semantics and indentation.  I'm curious to know if you find this more pleasing.

Comment: It's very different. I'm going to have to stare at it a while to understand it -- I don't even know all the symbols used, like `<=` and `:>`.

Comment: @Charles Okay.  You can select any of those tokens in the Notebook interface and press `F1` to bring up the documentation page.  `<=` is `LessEqual`, `:>` is `RuleDelayed`, and `/;` is `Condition`.  Once you become familiar with *Mathematica* patterns I think you will find it is not hard to read.

Comment: Without `Cube`: `Coords[r_]:={#1,#2,Floor[Sqrt[r^2-#1^2-#2^2]]}&@@@With[{t=Sqrt[r^2-1]},Select[Join@@Table[{x,y},{x,t},{y,1,x}],Norm[#]<=t&]];
Cubes[r_]:=(Cuboid/@(Union@@(Permute[#,SymmetricGroup[3]]&/@Coords[r])-1));`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Oh I know -- trust me, I used F1 a lot to construct my original program. I had never used any of `Cuboid`, `Norm`, `Permute`, `SymmetricGroup`, `Graphics3D`, `Opacity`, `Sphere`, or `ViewPoint` before. (I had used `<=`, but I wasn't sure if it was being used in some special way in your code -- I've seen that kind of construct used for set-builder notation in other languages.)

Comment: @DavidCarraher: `Coords` gives me an error in Mathematica 8.0.1.0. "Function::slotn : Slot number 2 in (expression) cannot be filled from (expression)." For example, `Coords[2]` returns `J‌oin[{{1, 1}, #2, {Floor[Sqrt[3 - #2^2]], Floor[Sqrt[3 - #2^2]]}}]`.

Comment: @Charles It appears that something strange happened to the code in David's comment -- probably a character encoding issue.  When I paste it into a Notebook `Join` is in blue, signifying an unassigned Symbol.  When typed `Join` over the top of it the code worked.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[`Translate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Translate.html) is probably the most efficient way to represent and display such a figure.

```
With[{r = 30},
 Graphics3D[{
   Translate[Cuboid[],
    Union @@ (Permute[#, SymmetricGroup[3]] & /@ Coords[r])
   ],
   {Green, Opacity[0.1], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]}
  }
 ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ah, much better. +1

Answer (score 3):

**New, not the best but can do**

```
r = 50;
da = Pi/(4. r);
sa = da;
ea = Pi/2. - da;

Composition[
  Graphics3D[{#, 
              GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionTransform /@ {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}]
             }, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 600] &,
  Cuboid /@ # &,
  {# - Sign[#], #} & /@ # &,
  Select[#, FreeQ[#, 0] &] &,
  DeleteDuplicates,
  Floor,
  Flatten[#, 1] &
  ][
 Table[r {Cos[d] Sin[a], Cos[d] Cos[a], Sin[d]}, {d, sa, ea, da}, {a, 
   sa, ea, da}]
 ]
```

[image]

**Old and slow** This is not optimal or faster code but it is cleaner:

```
r = 6;
s = 0;
e = r;
d = .5;

Composition[

  Graphics3D[{#}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, r}, {0, r}, {0, r}}] &,
  Flatten,
  Map[If[1 == Times @@ UnitStep[r - Norm /@ #], 
         {Hue@RandomReal[], Cuboid@#[[{1, -1}]]},
         ## &[]
        ] &, 
      #, {3}] &,      
  Map[Flatten[#, 2] &, #, {3}] &,
  Partition[#, {2, 2, 2}, 1] &

  ][Table[{i, j, k}, {i, s, e, d}, {j, s, e, d}, {k, s, e, d}]]
```

Important part of this code is function `Partition[#, {2, 2, 2}, 1] &` which does something like `{a,b,c} --> {{a,b},{b,c}}` but in 3D. It is clean but it is a big choke point. We have to create equally spaced array for this. Including points we know are to far away from origin.
You can add `Opacity@.7, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]` to `Graphics3D`, look out, opacity slows down rotation.
[image]

Comment: Thanks especially for the comment on opacity.